# Is it needed to connect all pages together or let the browser's back and forward buttons do the job

Tags: usability

I find it's comfortable to have the link to useful page in every single pages so the user can interact with our application conveniently. But sometimes, I find that the browser's buttons is convenience enough, and I don't know if users are more comfortable with link or browser's buttons.

Comment: There is no actual question here, it seems.

Comment: Although the question is poorly constructed I think it's not a duplicate of "Do users understand the browser back button?". The question here is if the back button is *enough*, not if it's used in the first place. See my (and the only) answer to this question: nowadays web apps may run in a chromeless browser setting which eliminates the back button thus requiring a different way to navigate the app.

Answer (score 0):

If it's important that users can reach all pages without using the browser buttons then absolutely do so: running web apps in chromeless environments is becoming more and more common.

Safari on iOS support this using [the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2).